# How to scroll to the first invalid input in angular forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working in an big angular Project. how can i scroll to the first invalid input in angular forms without using jquery ?

Comment: You need to add a working snippet or a link to codepen/jsfiddle with your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:-

```
myApp.directive('accessibleForm', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem) {

        // set up event handler on the form element
        elem.on('submit', function () {

            // find the first invalid element
            var firstInvalid = elem[0].querySelector('.ng-invalid');

            // if we find one, set focus
            if (firstInvalid) {
                firstInvalid.focus();
            }
        });
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: in which file i should write this code?

Comment: You can use it in directive like above.